# Set min/max size of JFileChooser - Java

Tags: java, swing, min, jfilechooser, minimum-size

I have a `JFileChooser` like this:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    //do something
}
```

And now I wnat to set the minimum/maximum size of it, because it looks bad if I decrease the size, else (That isn't even the smallest size possible):

[image: Example]

Couldn't I freeze the size of the `JFileChooser` if the user wants to make it smaller than for example this?:

[image: Example]

I've tried out this: `fileChooser.setMinimumSize(new Dimensio(400, 400));`, but it didnt work.
And I think it doesn't look good, if the size "jumps" back, when the user makes the window smaller, than for example `600p * 600p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass JFileChooser, and customize the dialog in its [createDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#createDialog-java.awt.Component-) method:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Override
    public JDialog createDialog(Component parent) {
        JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
        dialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        return dialog;
    }
};
```

You won’t gain much by doing this, though.  Other users will have different desktop themes and different fonts than you.  600×600 pixels may look good on your computer, but there is no guarantee it will be a good minimum size for others.  It’s best to just accept that users can make a window unusably small if they really want to.

Comment: You're rigth! 600p * 600p is a bit big, but I think it doesn't look good if it is just 10p * 10p big.